# require once adds a new line to response

Tags: php

I have the following class code in PHP:

```
<?php

require_once CUSTOM_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'myneighborlists.php'; 

class Action_Get_route extends Frapi_Action implements Frapi_Action_Interface
{

    /**
     * Required parameters
     * 
     * @var An array of required parameters.
     */
    protected $requiredParams = array();

    /**
     * The data container to use in toArray()
     * 
     * @var A container of data to fill and return in toArray()
     */
    private $data = array();

    /**
     * To Array
     * 
     * This method returns the value found in the database 
     * into an associative array.
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
        //$this->data['origin'] = $this->getParam('origin', self::TYPE_OUTPUT);
        //$this->data['destination'] = $this->getParam('destination', self::TYPE_OUTPUT);
        return $this->data;
    }

    /**
     * Default Call Method
     * 
     * This method is called when no specific request handler has been found
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function executeAction()
    {
        $valid = $this->hasRequiredParameters($this->requiredParams);
        if ($valid instanceof Frapi_Error) {
            return $valid;
        }

        return $this->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * Get Request Handler
     * 
     * This method is called when a request is a GET
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function executeGet()
    {
        $valid = $this->hasRequiredParameters($this->requiredParams);
        if ($valid instanceof Frapi_Error) {
            return $valid;
        }

        return $this->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * Post Request Handler
     * 
     * This method is called when a request is a POST
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function executePost()
    {
        $valid = $this->hasRequiredParameters($this->requiredParams);
        if ($valid instanceof Frapi_Error) {
            return $valid;
        }

        return $this->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * Put Request Handler
     * 
     * This method is called when a request is a PUT
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function executePut()
    {
        $valid = $this->hasRequiredParameters($this->requiredParams);
        if ($valid instanceof Frapi_Error) {
            return $valid;
        }

        return $this->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * Delete Request Handler
     * 
     * This method is called when a request is a DELETE
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function executeDelete()
    {
        $valid = $this->hasRequiredParameters($this->requiredParams);
        if ($valid instanceof Frapi_Error) {
            return $valid;
        }

        return $this->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * Head Request Handler
     * 
     * This method is called when a request is a HEAD
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function executeHead()
    {
        $valid = $this->hasRequiredParameters($this->requiredParams);
        if ($valid instanceof Frapi_Error) {
            return $valid;
        }

        return $this->toArray();
    }


}
```

This is basically a class template for a REST API and when I call the get method the response I got always has an extra new line in it. When I remove the require_once, that extra new line is gone. How do I avoid this extra new line? [This is](http://api.smartrekmobile.com/getroute.json) what I meant by a new line.

Comment: Examine myneighborlists.php. Probably there is an extra line break before `<?php` or after `?>`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See if there's an extra line or space after your close `?>` tags in the required file. There is probably something in the required file that is either echoing a space / line, or there's extra space at the end of the file.

Comment: It's worth noting that the PHP closing tag `?>` is always optional at the end of a file. By leaving it out you can halve the chance of this problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a whitespace char at the end of your file!

Comment: +1 for the solution, and +1 for the metalmatriarch.com referral ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this question without seeing the sourcecode of myneighborlists.php. My guess is, that there is an empty line at the top of this file before the `<?php`